# Print the next column after a match in gawk

Tags: awk, grep, gawk

I have a large file with multiple lines of text and columns, I have put a sample set below, the file comes from a windows server and the gawk is being run on windows fro  within DOS.

```
170228 000005 0499 DE(N) SortationHandler.sortationio.Comm Sending Telegram: <ItemEvent><312285164><25243153><EXTERNAL_REDIRECTED><2017-02-28 00:00:05.062+0300><1><><0157368350><previousScans><0><2><position><sorter#0><destinations><2><=TT1-CHU013><=TT1-CHU081><36>
170228 000005 0499 DE(N) SortationHandler.sortationio.Comm Sending Telegram: <ItemEvent><312285166><25243152><INDUCTED><2017-02-28 00:00:05.437+0300><1><><0157370126><previousScans><0><1><position><sorter#0><36><screenedSufficiently>
```

I want to be able to search for a specific string such as `<passengerName>` and then print out the **next** column and then add 3 or 4  other columns into the file output, I will always want the date and time at the start.

The issue is that the field position can change and is not static other than the date and time.

I have tried various gawk commands but nothing I try or have searched for gives me what I need.

```
gawk -F'[<>]''{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="<passengerName>")print$(i+1)}'
```

I would also like to output in a comma delimited file and remove the <> from around the columns

What I would like is an output something like the one below where I can pick the columns I need seperated by a comma

```
170228 000005,1FARHANA/MRS,QR118,QR
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: start with formatting your question text

Comment: RomansPerekhrest, there you go

Comment: also, show how should look the expected result

Comment: Thanks RomansPerekhrest

Comment: *print out the next column* - this `2017-02-28 00:00:05,` is not the next column value. I could help, but your expected output is unclear

Comment: Why not use `grep`?

Comment: add some more info about which other field to keep (criteria to select good fields)

Comment: Hi RomanPerekhrest, I have updated the question to hopefully make it clearer

Comment: Lluoluo - Happy to use grep if it can give me a similar output

Comment: You are also going to need the split command seeing as the date and time are not in fields delimited by <>

Comment: Pluse-uno for improving your first time Q per requests. In the future, structure your sample data so it is smaller. If you know how to solve it for 4 fields, you should easily be able to also solve for 14 or 44 or ..... right? ;-) . Given your error message below, also include the output of `uname -srv && awk --version` , Good luck.

Comment: Sorry don't quite understand the above comment.

Comment: my gawk version is - GNU Awk 3.1.3

Comment: @Fabby the point is for you to create a **Minimal** example. To get people interested in helping you, show us input with 4 or 5 fields that represents your problem, not 50 fields or however many you posted. See [ask] and in particular the part about creating a [mcve].

Comment: @Ed, 3 lines of data I though was minimal I left the length in so the people could see what I'm up against and the variations in  the file, does it really matter how long the string is in the post, I get the point if its thousands of lines long you wouldn't want to be scrolling down the page to see the problem.  Will amend for future posts either way.

Comment: Yes, it really matters. People who could help you have looked at your question, decided your sample was too wide to bother trying to understand the format of, and moved on (some after leaving comments). Hence you have 1 answer after 5 hours to what is probably a trivial problem. When you post sample input with a ton of lines OR a ton of fields on each line then it triggers the "if he can't be bothered to create a minimal example then why should I bother trying to understand it" reaction.

Comment: Thanks Ed for the pointer I have edited the sample data to make it more attractive to potential solution providers, let hope i can get some solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Several probems.

For one thing, you have problem with quotes. The shell would confuse between AWK quotes and shell quotes. After fixing the bug,

```
gawk -F '[<>]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i == "<passengerName>") print $(i+1)}'
```

Another thing, if your separators are [<>], then no word can be "", because words never contain delimiters.  After fixing the bug,

```
gawk -F '[<>]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i == "passengerName") print $(i+1)}'
```

Third, your words are delimited not by single '>' or '<'. They are delimited by "><", or "<", or ">".  You can mimick this with '[<>]+'. So finnally,

```
gawk -F '[<>]+' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i == "passengerName") print $(i+1)}'
```

Comment: Hi, if I change my script to yours about I get the error "> was unexpected at this time" ??

Comment: @Fabby : If your input file was created or was touched by an MS-Windows machine, try `cat -vet file | head -5` If you seen `^M$` at the end of each line, then you can remove the `^M` part by using `dos2unix file` . This may help, but  it is just a guess as what could be causing the problem. otherwise it's hard to know. Is there someone else at your job you can ask to look at your file/code/setup?. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter - the standard way to debug is to simplify the code (and data) and look when will the error vanish. Then you'll know where it the error.

Comment: OK, but if the O.P. has funky data, then better to correct that first. As we haven't heard back "that I figured it out, it is now working", I thought it would be helpful to eliminate a very common source of problems  (BTW, I did upvote  your answer ;-) ) . Good luck to all.

Comment: Hi guys sorry go caught up in other work !! I'm back on it now

Comment: Shellter, the file does come from a windows machine if I use the following adaptation

`gawk -F"[<>]+" "{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="passengerName") print $(i+1)}"`

and I get the following output

`rescanCount
currentDestination
currentDestinationId
rescanCount
currentDestination
currentDestinationId
carrierCnt
rescanCount`

Comment: It doesn't matter much where the file came from (except for line endings), it matters a whole lot more where you're running awk from since quoting rules for scripts vary - are you running it it Windows, or in UNIX (including cygwin)? Edit your question to state the OS you are running on - that also really matters!